# How to proceed with Task, await and async in background

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm facing a situation where I need help to understand how to proceed properly.

I have an Action that is a kind of form for budget. After the user fills all fields, the user will save the budget pressing the Send button.

The Send button will save the data and then, will send an e-mail to all companies. When I say all companies, I mean around 1000 companies.

But, the problem is that when I press the button Send, the page get locked when sending the e-mails for the companies and after sending an e-mail to all companies, the website return the view.

What I would like to do is, when the user press Send button, the websites saves the budget, start to send e-mail in background, and almost instantly return the view to the user, HOWEVER, while this, the website is sending e-mails in background to 1000 companies.

How did I do this? Here is the signature of my methods:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> EnviarProposta(PostOrcamentoServicoProposta proposta)
{
    // persist the budget
    SaveData(proposta);

    // get all companies...
    var companies = getCompanies(proposta);

    foreach (var company in companies)
        await EmailFactory.SendBudget(proposta, company).SendAsync();

    return PartialView(proposta);
}
```

SendAsync is the async method of SMTP.

The question is, how do I simple throw the send e-mail method to background and return the view, without waiting the sending complete?

The second problem is that I'm using a framework that convert a View in an Email, so, for that we'll need the Context of the controller.

Should I use task.factory.startnew?

### Should I use Thread?

**Considerations:**
Unfortunately, asynchronous controller actions does not help in this scenario, because they do not yield response to the user while waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete. They only solve internal issues related to thread pooling and application capacity.

Comment: essentially you need to fire up a thread and execute the sending of emails on that thread so it takes the responsibility off of the current thread serving the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're hosting this via asp.net, the proper way is a bit complicated.

Queuing work via a thread doesn't notify the runtime that there is work to be done. That means when the app domain is recycled (which is done from time to time without your intervention), your queued work is not guaranteed to finish. If that doesn't concern you, proceed with queuing up a background task.

The "proper" way to do this is to persist that work somehow (message queue, sql server, etc...) and have another host run it.

See this [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) for more details/possible solutions.

Comment: Interesting insight, that a long running piece of work is not guaranteed to finish in an ASP.Net environment if application recycle occurs.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx   One of the suggested Minimal entry alternatives then is HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => SendMailAsync(user.Email));

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of queueing up the emails that need to be sent, and having another service actually performing the sending...

... particularly because it appears there is some work being done per email.

For example, you could just create an entry in a database, from which the other service works, and flags them as sent.  If the contents of your email are actually generated by a call to a view, then the separate service should still be able to simply call the respective Action via a **WebRequest** or similar.

Then you can also mark the workload as completed, and have evidence to that fact.

Comment: I like too the idea of queuing up the the emails that need to be send, and I believe that it is the most correct way in large scale, like this case. There is no miracle to do, however, while this, I need to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. For example, you can simply remove **await** from your code above. Or you can use LINQ and get your tasks array to use continuation.

```
Task[] tasks = companies.Select(c => EmailFactory.SendBudget(proposta).SendAsync(c)).ToArray();
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, t => { /*do something*/ });
```

(I assume you need to pass company to each Send method call somehow)

Or as Ahmed mentioned, you can start a thread and send emails in it, this way or another.

Answer (score -2):

If you need a "Fire and Forget" method, consider using Task.Factory.StartNew().

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
{
    foreach(Company c in companies)
    {
        // send your email here, make sure you have good error handling!
        EmailFactory.SendBudget(proposta)
    }
});
```

Comment: As a note to the OP, since as you mention, this is "fire and forget" so if all 1000 emails fail for example, the UI would give no indication that anything was wrong.

Comment: There is no problem about no indication @dman2306 because I have a table that register when something goes wrong. The problem is that I will need the controller Context because the EmailFactory use a Framework that converts a View(that uses the context) in an Email.

Comment: What do you need out of the Controller's Context?

Comment: @Greg, context is used to render the email. I'm using a framework that convert a View in an e-mail, so, for that I need the context.

Comment: Why the down vote exactly?  Logging/Error handling should be the responsibility of the email engine and not the controller.